# Freeing GPU Memory PyTorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

So, my code is supposed to work as follows: import the images, get the embeddings from ResNet model, use those embeddings in a NN (user created) and run the analysis. ResNet imports the weights (pretrained=True) and requires grad has been set False for all parameters.
I have a lot of images to process, more than my RAM can handle. So, what I do is, I import batches of images, run them through the GPU, get the embeddings of the images, and save the results to some files (I have like 120k images, so I create a file for every 10k images, my RAM can handle that much). I then import each file in a loop and run them through my NN. The reason I am doing this is to save time when running for every epoch (So that I don't have to run ResNet each epoch). The issue I am facing however is that when I save the tensors (ResNet embeddings) to the file, I do it on the GPU since it is much much faster. However, when the saving is done, even though everything is done inside a function, the GPU RAM is not released and as such training cannot continue. I even tried deleting the tensors but it still didn't work.
My code is sth like this (overly simplified):

```
def save_to_file(model, imgs_batch):
  imgs_batch = model(imgs_batch.to('cuda'))
  torch.save(imgs_batch, file)
  del imgs_batch
model = resnet().to('cuda')
for each batch:
  imgs_batch = import_images(...)  # Imports images in a (batch size, 3, 224, 224) Tensor
  save_to_file(model, imgs_batch)
del model
```

Comment: Have you tried [`torch.cuda.empty_cache()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#torch.cuda.empty_cache) after deleting the model?

Comment: Yes, I have. It frees some of the memory, but not all of it. I think the model still remains. I was thinking maybe I could overwrite the model, when I am using my own created NN.
I also tried some things on the python console. I created a random tensor, sent it to the GPU, deleted it, and then called empty cache. Then I created another random tensor, and tried to send it to the GPU, it gave the OOM error. I don't know why but empty cache IMO is not doing its job properly.

Comment: If you use Jupyter and previously had error in the same session. Try restart kernel.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking of doing that as well. I just find it weird how PyTorch (or maybe it is Python's fault) won't release the GPU memory.